# Unity Script with an Update Function attached to multiple Objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
//GUI Function
private void Update()
{

    healthMeterPos.position = WorldToGuiPoint(new Vector2(position.xPos,position.yPos));
}
```

This is my Update Function which is in a Parent class from which all my gameobjects inherit problem though is that it's only updating the Position for the first GameObject not all of them. Anybody know why?

Comment: What is healthMeterPos?

Comment: Please show the full class and subclass code, and object hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

When you write `healthMeteorPos.position = ...`, unless `healthMeteorPos` is either `public` or `[SerializeField]` and set uniquely to each one of the objects *separatedly*, all the object basically execute the same command **over the same target** which is one object `healthMeteorPos`.

If you post a little more code we could help more, but generally speaking, if you want every object to affect itself, use `transform.position` instead of assigning the position of another shared object.